Function to process rows in table results in '(wrong-type-argument sequencep 1.0e+INF)' error
A function that copies the contents of a table column to the clipboard often results in the error (wrong-type-argument sequencep 1.0e+INF) and I think it is the result of some numeric sequences being misinterpreted or overflowing.
When I prefix the figures in the column with a #, eg change 975a5d4f to #975a5d4f, the problem goes away.
(defun rc/org-table-get-current-column()
  "Copy the contents of the current table's column to the clipboard. refs #49d4e460."
      
  (interactive)
  
  (if (eq (org-at-table-p) nil) (user-error "This is not a table"))

  (let* (
         (firsthline (lambda (x) (if (> (length x) 1) (aref x 1) '())))
         (column (org-table-current-column ))
         (table-list (progn (org-table-analyze)
                            (org-babel-del-hlines
                             (nthcdr (if (eq (funcall firsthline org-table-hlines) nil)
                                         0 (1+ (funcall firsthline org-table-hlines)))
                                     (org-babel-read-table)))))

         (table-file (mapconcat (lambda (x) (nth (1- column) x)) table-list "\n")))
    (kill-new table-file)
    table-file))

Is there some way temporary mode the interpreter can be set to read values as uninterpreted text without trying to convert it?
The code basically converts the table to a set of lists via org-babel-read-table and picks out the Nth element of each list which corresponds with the contents of the table row at N.

Your code may need some comments...

The mapconcat requires strings and you are giving it whatever Org mode decides (numbers in some cases, strings in others). So as you mention, you need a way to read the table without converting entries to numbers (leave them as strings), but org-babel-read which is used by org-babel-read-table does not provide any escape from that mechanism. You'll need to write your own org-babel-read-table to do that.

Instead of saying (eq <foo> nil), the more idiomatic way is to say (not <foo>).
